# Как сделать post запрос в requests, чтобы сервер понял что я ищу и перешёл на страницу с результатами?

Tags: python, парсер, post, requests, get

У Федерального института промышленной собственности (ФИПС) есть сайт в котором можно найти информацию о патентах https://www.fips.ru/iiss/search.xhtml. Перейдя по ссылке можно увидеть, что есть форма, через которую он принимает информацию для поиска, после чего нужно нажать кнопку поиск и он переходит на https://www.fips.ru/iiss/search_res.xhtml?faces-redirect=true. Раньше я использовал параметры URL c get запросом, а здесь их нет. Как я могу создать get или post запрос с нужными параметрами библиотекой requests, чтобы получить список нужных мне патентов?

Answer (score 1):

Советую использовать библиотеку [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc.ru/) для парсинга

Из нее вам нужен редирект, то есть алгоритм действий примерно такой:|

1. Парсите [ссылку](https://www.fips.ru/iiss/search.xhtml)
2. Задаете параметры, через get редирект
3. Переходите и ищете с параметрами

Примерно так видимо:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = requests.Session()
url='https://www.fips.ru/iiss/search.xhtml'
r=html=s.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
relative_link=soup.find('a',{'id':'download'})['href'] #Получаем ссылку для поиска
download_redirect_link=url+relative_link
headers={
"referer": url
}
r2=requests.get(download_redirect_link,headers=headers)
print(r2.url)
```

И дальше с ней работаем